# MySQL Finding totals in multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

We have an app that helps people find other people to play basketball. We are associated with some basketball courses in the city. So I have been tasked to find 'how many times players who play at XXField (field_id = 460), play basketball the whole year'

I am not sure I understand what to do very well. These are the tables I am dealing with

**Game_users Table**

```
game_id | user_id | bill_id | created_at          | deleted_at
23455   | 3455    | 234     | 2019-02-06 03:16:40 | null
45678   | 6790    | 877     | 2020-02-09 07:26:34 | null
87666   | 2546    | 899     | 2020-04-20 06:06:06 | null
12312   | 1231    | 989     | 2019-02-22 09:22:31 | null
```

**Games Table** (that includes the basketball field's id)

```
id   | field_id | game_status| created_at          | deleted_at
23455| 460      | Completed  | 2019-02-06 03:16:40 | null
23455| 345      | Completed  | 2020-09-03 05:45:33 | null
87666| 460      | Completed  | 2020-12-12 08:34:22 | null
87666| 212      | Completed  | 2020-11-23 09:54:12 | null
```

I know I have to join both tables to get the field id and the players that played there. But how do I also get the total times they played golf this year as well? including the ones they played at 460.

I am sorry this is confusing, it's very confusing to me too.

My expected results would be something like

```
User_Id | Total Games | FieldXX Number of Games
1234    | 34          |  12
```

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: And what does "play basketball the whole year" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sub-query in `IN` clause and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT GU.USER_ID,
       COUNT(1)
  FROM GAME_USERS AS GU
WHERE GU.GAME_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM GAMES AS G WHERE G.FIELD_ID = 460)
AND .. CONDITION ON created_at FOR WHOLE YEAR ACCORDING TO YOUR REQUIREMENT
GROUP BY GU.USER_ID
```